# urlDownloadToFile error 2147467260 in VB6

Tags: vb6, download

I am using urlDownloadToFile API in VB6 to download an executable file from server. The API returns an error code 2147467260 (Transaction aborted)

The problem is reproducible only on a certain computer (win7).

What can be a problem? Is there a quick fix that does not involve installation of third party downloaders?

thank you

Comment: How do you call `UrlDownloadToFile` (show some code). Note that `-2147467260 = &H80004004 = E_ABORT` which can be caused if any callback signals abort.

Comment: `URLDownloadToFile(0, http://localhost:8080/test.exe, c:\myFiles\test.exe, 0, 0)`

What do you mean by "_any callback signals abort_"?

Comment: Is there an anti-virus program on the user's machine?

Comment: there is antivirus, but user said that he configured it correctly and I cannot login to his computer. Can I use WebBrowser control instead? Or it will face the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User was not an administrator on his computer. As a solution, he should run the program as admin.