# MS Access VBA DownloadFile returning error -2147467260

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to download a file from the internet and I am getting this error code: `-2147467260`. The location can be accessed with no issues from IE. This is the code I am using:

```
Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
    "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
    ByVal szURL As String, _
    ByVal szFileName As String, _
    ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
    ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
    Dim lngRetVal      As Long
    lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
    If lngRetVal = 0 Then DownloadFile = True
End Function
```

Comment: For those of us who haven't memorized all of the error numbers, could you give us a clue as to what the error message *said*?

Comment: `lngRetVal = -2147467260` instead of being this: `lngRetVal = 0`. There is no description

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, the error number means [Operation Aborted](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=227579) or [Transaction aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11217138/6884).

The second link is a question here at Stack Overflow and the answer says that it works when you run the program as admin.

So there are two things that you can try:

1. Run as admin, like mentioned before
2. Try a different file (to be sure). For example, I'm on Windows 7 right now, my user has admin privileges and I just successfully downloaded [this file](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico) with the code from your question.

Comment: I think this link (http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=227579) you provided might help but I am having trouble pointing to what exactly the author changed to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the filename. I am generating filenames from an Access Database and the table was adding trailing spaces. I am investing where these trailing spaces came from.

Comment: So you tried another file like I suggested in my answer, and that worked?

Comment: Yes, the issue was an invalid filename. My application was generating invalid filename (i.e. `tests                           .xls`). There were some trailing spaces that needed to be cleared out.