# Accessing Outlook via C# - COMException when checking a message's sender but not the subject?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, comexception

I'm using Visual Studio and Outlook 2010. I am able to connect to my local Outlook default profile and list the messages in the Inbox, but I can only get the SentOn, Subject, and EntryID properties. As soon as I try to access the SenderName or Body (and a few others), I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467260
  Message=Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))
  Source=""
  ErrorCode=-2147467260
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_SenderName()
       at reademail.Program.ReadMail() in h:\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 54
       at reademail.Program.Main(String[] args) in h:\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 20
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

The COMException is so vague it's maddening. I've searched and searched and can't find anything that has helped. I've tried delaying the system thread, and I've tried the `MailItem.GetInspector` trick for each item, too.

I am working in a corporate environment where I don't have local admin privileges on my machine, and neither will the individual who uses the software. Getting local admin will be a pain in rear, so I'd like to be really sure that's the problem before starting the process.

Here's the minimal code that produces the error. I would greatly appreciate any help!

```
using System;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace MinimalExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Correctly triggers my local Outlook to open, allowing me to select the desired profile
            Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook._NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

            //Correctly opens the Inbox and reports the correct stats
            Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            Console.WriteLine("Folder Name: {0}", inboxFolder.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Num Items: {0}", inboxFolder.Items.Count.ToString());

            for (int counter = 1; counter <= inboxFolder.Items.Count; counter++)
            {
                //This cast ensures you only deal with valid MailItems and not calendar issues
                Outlook.MailItem item = inboxFolder.Items[counter] as Outlook.MailItem;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    //The following works fine
                    Console.WriteLine("Item: {0}", counter.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("EntryID: {0}", item.EntryID);
                    Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}", item.Subject);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0} {1}", item.SentOn.ToLongDateString(), item.SentOn.ToLongTimeString());

                    //Enabling any of the following two lines causes the E_ABORT COMException
                    //Console.WriteLine("Sendername: {0}", item.SenderName);
                    Console.WriteLine("Body: {0}", item.Body);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT: What I ended up doing**

Doing the software as a plugin sidestepped the security issues, but this is far from ideal. I just can't believe that .NET can't do this sort of work without local admin access. If anybody knows of a way to accomplish this as a standalone console app **without** local admin, I would love to hear. Many thanks!

Comment: `E_ABORT` might simply mean that Outlook is busy at the moment. You could try retrying with a delay a couple of times, and see if that helps. It might be that it needs to contact e.g. your Exchange server or run the e-mail through a virus scanner or something.

Comment: Thanks, Luaan. I tried a few timing tricks (including `MailItem.GetInspector`), but nothing helped. Looks like I'm going to need to talk to the IT guys. I was really hoping this would work pretty much out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f0a76f44-704e-4454-b44e-c95b3f60eff5/cant-send-email?forum=vsto

Here is another type of problem with same exception.

There is an answer like that:
"...In other words, if you want full access to the Outlook object model, so that methods like Send and SaveAs work unimpeded, that's the Outlook.Applicatiom object you need to use."

And here is another one with same error code:

[urlDownloadToFile error 2147467260 in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217138/urldownloadtofile-error-2147467260-in-vb6)

I think it's all about your account privileges.

Comment: First, thanks for the reply! It just seems so random. Why can I see the subject but not the body, for example? Is it really true that no standalone .NET application can do this sort of work without full local admin privileges? That sounds crazy. I'll try coding it as a plugin and see if that sidesteps the issue.

Comment: Hi again, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161047.aspx in this page, Microsoft describes something like Permission Model for Outlook Add-Ins like you used. Basicly, this model gives different types of permissions to different users. Basic permission is Restricted(I think you have this type of permission). With Restricted permission you can access mail subject or sender, but you can't access the mail body. You can find a lot of information about those permissions on the website.

Comment: Thanks, Firat. This is very helpful now that I've moved the software into an actual add-in. Before, I was just trying to write a small console app to get in and get out, but it looks like I have to go all the way down the rabbit hole with this one. So far, anyway, I'm able to access the information I need. Sure would be nice if the error message I got actually said something about permissions and not just a generic E_ABORT!!